# Accessing service container in a class

Tags: symfony

I want to be able to use `$this->container` in class below but how do I pass container to it with yml below? Or do I really need to pass it to access `$this->container->getParameter('currency');` ?
I did all the others as the example shows but failing to pass the container!

Thanks in advance

I have this code in config.yml:

```
services:
    data_cash:
            class:        Booking\FrontendBundle\WebService\CashManager
            arguments:    [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager, %paymentCallback%, %kernel.environment%]
```

This is the CashManager class:

```
class CashManager
{
    public function __construct($entityManager, $callback, $environment, $CONTAINER)
    {
        //$this->currency = $CONTAINER->getParameter('currency');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bad idea to pass the entire container, but you have to add this in arguments: `@service_container` .

If you what only the parameter "currency" you have to add this: `%currency%`

Comment: OK. How can I make it better?

Comment: I only need this: $this->container->getParameter('currency'); so how do I only inject that?

Comment: Learner something new. Thanks